# why Try-catch without body works for unchecked exception but why not for checked exception,

Tags: java

```
public class ExceptionExample {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        try{}
        //catch(SQLException e){} //Compile time Error
        catch(Exception e){} // No Error
    }
}
```

Comment: `RuntimeException`s need not be mentioned in the method signature, therefore there's no way for the compiler to check, if an method call could throw a certain `RuntimeException` or not, but for non-`RuntimeException`s its different. But the answer to your question is simply: "Because the java specification says so."

Answer (score 1):

because `SQLException` is not a `RuntimeException`, i.e. no code written in try block can throw it without declaring it,

where `Exception` could be a `RuntimeException`

Answer (score 0):

Checked exceptions must call a method the actually throws that exception, in the try clause.